# Create a project with the "npx react-native init AwesomeProject" command, and then execute the "yarn android" command to report an error

Tags: react-native

**Create a project with the "npx react-native init AwesomeProject" command, and then execute the "yarn android" command to report an error**（I didn't make any code changes）

```bash
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
      > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:.
        Required by:
            project :
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin.
        Required by:
            project :
         > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a 
library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:
             - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified 
declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8 
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')        
             - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')        
                     - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)
             - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')        
             - Variant 'testResultsElementsForTest' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')        
                     - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat tasks FAILURE: Build failed 
with an exception. * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'. > Could not determine the dependencies of null. > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:. Required by: project : > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin. Required by: project : > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with 
Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but: - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally: - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with 
Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8 - Other compatible attribute: - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1') - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally: - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library - Other compatible attributes: - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8) - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar) - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1') - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime) - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally: - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8 - Other compatible attribute: - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1') - Variant 'testResultsElementsForTest' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified: 
- Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library - Other compatible attributes: - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally) - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8) - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar) - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1') - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime) * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at 
https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 2s.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**But checking with react native doctor there is no error**

yarn run v1.13.0
$ react-native doctor
Common
✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies

Android
✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

Errors:   0
Warnings: 0
Done in 6.41s.

I re-executed the yarn command, trying to fix this error, but without success

Comment: The latest version is broken/poo so just use an older version such as:  '''  npx react-native@0.71 init AwesomeProject --version 0.71 '''

Answer (score -1):

tries to do everything with npm:

1. install last npm version: `npm install -g react-native-cli.`
2. create your new Project: `expo init newProject`
3. `cd new Project`

and just try: `npm start`

Comment: expo is very limited in what libraries you can use, maybe that's why they want to use react native